# Make lodash globally available in a react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash, metro-bundler

Does anyone know if you can make lodash available in every file in a react native project so you don’t have to import it.

Answer (score 1):

You can shim `_` globally with the webpack [`ProvidePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/). The webpack [documentation page on shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) does this step by step, but essentially you just need to add the plugin to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
  const path = require('path');
+ const webpack = require('webpack');
 
  module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
+   plugins: [
+     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
+       _: 'lodash',
+     }),
+   ],
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This looks like it works with react but not with our react native project as it now uses the metro bundler.

Comment: Ah, damn! I wonder if you could just do `global._ = _` after importing lodash in the entry point file, then just access `global._` (not sure if you can drop the global. when a cessing)